# Using days and months as levels in hierarchy

Tags: multilevel-analysis

I have two different sources for order / purchase related data, one is at individual (purchase) level, the other is aggregated daily. Both sources contain different *types* of data points, albeit all related to purchases. I want to use this data to model changes in purchase patterns. My question is can I use individual vs daily records as seperate levels? Does it make sense to use time itself as a level in a hierarchy? Until now I've mostly seen schools, states, cities, etc. being used as levels, I never saw examples using time.

The alternative, I guess, is to summarize points in the specific source so it becomes daily, but I am guessing I could be losing some valueable information that way.

Any ideas would be appreciated,